# How to create factories for models with nested_attributes in Factorybot

Tags: ruby, rspec, associations, nested-attributes

I want to test following controller with RSpec

**coupons_controller.rb:**

```
class Api::V1::CouponsController < ApiController
  def index
    if params[:profile_id]
      @coupons = Profile.find(params[:profile_id]).coupons
    end
  end
end
```

I want to know

1) How to create factories with `FactoryBot` (`spec/factories/profiles.rb`, `coupons.rb`,  `coupon_profiles.rb`)

2)How to write `spec/controllers/coupons_controllers.rb`:

### associations

profile.rb

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :coupon_profiles
end
```

coupon.rb

```rb
class Coupon < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :coupon_profiles
end
```

coupon_profile.rb

```
class CouponProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :coupon
  belongs_to :profile
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```rb
# spec/factories/profiles.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :profile, class: 'Profile', do
    # ...
  end
end
# spec/factories/coupons.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :coupon, class: 'Coupon' do 
    # ...
  end
end
# spec/factories/coupon_profiles.rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :coupon_profile, class: 'CouponProfile' do
    coupon
    profile
  end
end
```

Honestly, your best bet is reviewing the GETTING_STARTED README for [FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) -- everything you want to know is in there, with examples. It is a shining example of a README. (Note on the use of `class` in my example above, there are [specific performance reasons to use the stringified class name instead of the class constant](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#specifying-the-class-explicitly))

For your controller specs, have you reviewed the [RSpec Documentation](https://rspec.info/features/6-0/rspec-rails/request-specs/request-spec/)? Though it's [recommended](https://rspec.info/documentation/6.0/rspec-rails/#request-specs) that you use more functional testing like Request specs instead of controller specs. You should be able to do something like:

```
describe 'coupons' do 
  subject { response }

  shared_examples_for 'success' do
    before { request }

    it { should have_http_status(:success) }
  end

  describe 'GET /coupons' do
    let(:request) { get coupons_path }

    it_behaves_like 'success'
  end

  describe 'GET /coupons/:profile_id' do
    let(:request) { get coupon_path(profile)
    let(:profile) { coupon_profile.profile }
    let(:coupon_profile) { create :coupon_profile }

    it_behaves_like 'success'
  end
end
```

Comment: You're the woman! Using `class` was what I was after for an inner class, e.g. `Coupon::Profile`. Thanks!